# Angularjs layover focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can not put focus on a `<span>`

I have a directive `focus-here`. When set to `true` it focuses on the input field.

Upon showing a popup layer with an error message I want to focus on the `Close` or `X` button.

I am using `AngularJS 1.4.7`. Even when I create a button that calls

```
document.getElementById('closespan').focus();
```

on `ng-click` it does not work.

Comment: can you share more code please

Comment: @Vineet Here is the div that sits in my view `<div ng-show="dberror==true" class="glob-error"><div class="inner">Unable to reach the database
<span class="x-style" ng-click="dberror=false">X</span></div></div>`   . It shows when i set the value of dberror=true and it works perfectly i need to focus on the `<span>` containing the `X`

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in plnkr?

Answer (score 0):

The `span` element is not focusable by default. You need to add a `tabindex="0"` attribute to your element and the browser will know not to ignore it.

Comment: no there is another problem as even upon changing the `span` to `button` it still does not work.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Although the observation stands, you can't focus on a select by default. Per my other comment, if you could reproduce the issue on Plunker, it would be easier to help you troubleshoot your code.